# firefox 43.0.4 doesn't show my custom font

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

first of all, i want to say that i searched and found many questions like this, and i almost tried every way of solving the problem. but they didn't work. and please consider that this problem is not for all of the pages in firefox. it's just for 1 page.
i have a very simple html page like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
@font-face{
font-family: 'BYekan';
  src: url('http://bloglikecms.com/tempblogfa/BYekan.eot?#') format('eot'),  /* IE6�8 */
       url('http://bloglikecms.com/tempblogfa/BYekan.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
       url('http://bloglikecms.com/tempblogfa/BYekan.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Saf3�5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
body{
    font-family: 'BYekan',tahoma !important;
text-align: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>سلام</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In safari, it works well. but in firefox, it doesn't show my custom font. this problem is just for this page. i visit many websites with custom fonts and firefox shows that pages correctly with the custom fonts. so i want to know why this happens with my page and where i did wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that "Allow pages to use their own fonts, instead of my selections above" is checked in Preferences > Content > Fonts & colors > Advanced (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101721/firefox-font-face-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 0):

You can Download font files and save them in same directory where you have the html file and it will work for all browsers :

```
   @font-face{
        font-family: 'BYekan';
        src: url('BYekan.eot') format('eot'),  /* IE6�8 */
        url('BYekan.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
        url('BYekan.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Saf3�5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
    }
```

Comment: i can't do that because it's a blogging service. i want to use the font in my blog template

Answer (score 0):

Mention `<!DOCTYPE html>` and try once..

Comment: @raghavendraraghu it didn't work :) also i didn't expect it to work because what you wrote is not related :)

Comment: I thought that is one of the reason... and i tried in my local same problem i faced getting errors like: Cross-Origin Request Blocked so font downloading is failed... so i am suggesting that download fonts and try it will work.. it works for me.